# Disable window animations when the menu option is missing?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

How do I set *Window animation scale* and *Transition animation scale* to *Animation off* when  the option to do so is not available on my ROM (though it ought to be). Specifically it should be under *Developer options* in *Settings* but all of the *User interface* options are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have root, you can edit the Settings database through adb:

```
adb shell
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
sqlite> update system set value=0 where name='window_animation_scale';
sqlite> update system set value=0 where name='transition_animation_scale';
sqlite> .exit
# exit
adb reboot
```

I first attempted to edit the field with the SQLite Editor app from the Play Store: `Settings Storage (com.android.providers.settings) → settings.db → system → window_animation_scale` but it unfortunately gave me `Update failed - error code 5: database is locked`. Whereas updating the database from adb worked fine. (Perhaps a different app would also work.)

Other settings are also editable this way.

If sqlite3 says permission denied you may need to chmod it to allow execution. You also may need to find the right path to use above for the settings.db file, here's an example:

```
# find / -name sqlite3
/system/xbin/sqlite3
# chmod 755 /system/xbin/sqlite3
# find / -name settings.db
/dbdata/databases/com.android.providers.settings/settings.db
```