# How to turn off animation in Lenovo A6000 Plus

Tags: settings, lenovo-a6000-plus

I am using Lenovo A6000 Plus smartphone.

I want to turn off all the animations. But in  Developer options there are only few options. The animation option is missing. I searched but I didn't find anything.

[image: Here is the Screen shot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Previously answered here (it involves having your phone rooted though): http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53720/disable-window-animations-when-the-menu-option-is-missing

Answer (score 0):

There was an app released a long time ago that might be able to do this for you called [Spare Parts Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidgram.spareparts)