# How to edit hidden settings from Developer options?

Tags: settings, menu, hidden

I have a chinese tablet with very specific Android 4.4.2 ROM - it's Developer options menu has only USB debugging available, and all other settings are hidden.

The problem is that i switched off the Developer options toggle by mistake, so now all settings are back to their defaults, including the transitional animations (when changing tabs) period.

[image]

They was not active before, so it was the default behavior of the ROM.

The device is not rooted.

Is there any way to edit the hidden settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm uncertain on bringing those lost options in GUI back other than to recommend clearing data of Settings app from Settings → Apps → All apps → Settings → Clear data. Reboot and see what happens. In the event of failure, you can consider [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset).

That said, if you're simply concerned with changing Window/Transition animation scale and/or Animator duration scale, then you can use `settings` or `content` tool which do not require root access. You can refer to Christopher Galpin's [method](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/53721/96277) for an approach requiring root access.

<sub>(Solution tested on Android 4.2.1, 4.4.2, 5.0.2 and 5.1.1.)</sub>

Setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) in PC and execute

```
adb shell settings get system  window_animation_scale    # for Window animation scale. Some ROMs have this key under global table instead of system. So replace system if command gives null
adb shell content query --uri content://settings/system --where 'name="window_animation_scale"'  # an alternative to above command. Make replacements as appropriate
```

If the first and the second command returns you a decimal and a string beginning with `Row:`, then you're on the right track. Now do

```
adb shell settings put system  window_animation_scale VALUE   # Replace VALUE with a decimal, such as 0.75 or 2.0. The minimum and maximum I've seen are 0.0 and 10.0
adb shell content update --uri content://settings/system --bind value:s:VALUE --where 'name="window_animation_scale"'  # an alternative to above command. Make replacements as appropriate
```

In order to change Transition animation scale, replace `window_animation_scale` with `transition_animation_scale`. For Animator duration scale, replace with `animator_duration_scale`.